# How to access an array from another class

Tags: java, multithreading

I want to operate on the array called "players" that is declared in the main method.  I want to use "players" in my class called "Glucksspielthread" 
I know that I can't access "players" because it is declared in the main method and is not visible for other classes.

How can I solve this problem? Here is my code:

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class Glucksspieltest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int numPlayers = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        int threadSize = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);

        ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threadSize);
        Glucksspielthread[] players = new Glucksspielthread[numPlayers];
        for (int i = 0; i < numPlayers; i++) {
            players[i] = new Glucksspielthread(i);
            es.execute(players[i]);
        }
    }
}

class Thinker {
    public static void think(int Millisekunden) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(Millisekunden);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void randomThink(int minMillisekunden, int      maxMillisekunden) {
        System.out.println("test");
    }
}

class Glucksspielthread implements Runnable {
    public int playerNumber;

    Glucksspielthread(int number) {
            playerNumber = number;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i <= playerNumber; i++) {
            // here, I want to operate on array called "players" that is   declared in the main method  
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: make it public and static

Comment: Just make the array a variable field after the declaration of your class and you can use it anywhere inside Glucksspieltest.

Comment: I want to use it in the class "Glucksspielthread"

Comment: @dumitru what do you mean? the array ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for your test purpose make your players variable static and public in the Glucksspieltest class, like this:

```
public class Glucksspieltest {

public static Glucksspielthread[] players;
```

Then acces it in the Glucksspielthread class like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= playerNumber; i++) {
        // here, I want to operate on array called "players" that is   declared in the main method
        Glucksspieltest.players
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but when I try this: for(int i=0; i<= playerNumber; i++) { Glucksspieltest.players[i] =10;}
he throws an error "cannot convert from int to Glucksspielthread"

Comment: better way make it 'players' private instead of public and access it by Glucksspieltest.getterPlayer()

Comment: @ArvindGangwar it's correct for a production code, as I mention only for test/

Answer (score 1):

Add a method to class `Glucksspieltest`, and make the players array global:

```
public class Glucksspieltest {
    private static Glucksspielthread[] players;

    public static Glucksspielthread[] getPlayers(){
        return players;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int numPlayers = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        int threadSize = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);

        ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threadSize);
        players = new Glucksspielthread[numPlayers];
        for (int i = 0; i < numPlayers; i++) {
            players[i] = new Glucksspielthread(i);
            es.execute(players[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

This way you can get the array by calling the `getPlayers()` method.

*(Note that, it would be adviced to add a constructor to initialize and fill the `players` array, and separate the player management from the `main` method as well.)*

Answer (score 0):

Make players as private global referance variable

```
public class Glucksspieltest {
//Make a Global reference variable players
   private static Glucksspielthread[] players; 

// Make a getter Method to get players
 public static Glucksspielthread[] getPlayers(){
    return players;
}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int numPlayers = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        int threadSize = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);

        ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threadSize);

        players = new Glucksspielthread[numPlayers];
        for (int i = 0; i < numPlayers; i++) {
            players[i] = new Glucksspielthread(i);
            es.execute(players[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

And access it by Glucksspieltest.getPlayers();

```
class Glucksspielthread implements Runnable {
    public int playerNumber;

     private static Glucksspielthread[] players;

    Glucksspielthread(int number) {
            playerNumber = number;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i <= playerNumber; i++) {
            // here, I want to operate on array called "players" that is declared in the main method  
         players= Glucksspieltest.getPlayers();  // play with players
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And what happens when I want that every singe player in the array shall get  10 Dollars to play. Glucksspieltest.getplayers[i] wont work. How can I operator on the array fields of "players" ?